# InputFunction error on Snakemake when returning a list of file with a lambda function

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm writing a snakemake rule which will take input values from a parased yaml and return the files that are associated with that group label as a list, but I am getting an odd error.

I've got my function printing the return output before it returns so it seems to be returning a list alright

```
['/SAN/vyplab/alb_projects/data/muscle/analysis/feature_counts/Ctrl1_featureCounts_results.txt', '/SAN/vyplab/alb_projects/data/muscle/analysis/feature_counts/Ctrl4_featureCounts_results.txt', '/SAN/vyplab/alb_projects/data/muscle/analysis/feature_counts/Ctrl2_featureCounts_results.txt', '/SAN/vyplab/alb_projects/data/muscle/analysis/feature_counts/Ctrl3_featureCounts_results.txt']
```

However I am get an "AttributeError" which is unexpected espicially since I've straight adapted this from some previous pipeline that worked perfectly well with this function

```
InputFunctionException in line 26 of /SAN/vyplab/alb_projects/pipelines/rna_seq_snakemake/rules/deseq2_featureCounts.smk:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'list'
Wildcards:
bse=control
contrast=ContrastvControl
```

Rule looks like this, am ommitting the shell and params calls as they're not necessary to debug I think

```
rule run_standard_deseq:
    input:
        base_group = lambda wildcards: featurecounts_files_from_contrast(wildcards.bse),
        contrast_group = lambda wildcards: featurecounts_files_from_contrast(wildcards.contrast)
    output:
        os.path.join(DESEQ2_DIR,"{bse}_{contrast}" + "normed_counts.csv.gz")
```

Implementation of the helper function

```
def featurecounts_files_from_contrast(grp):
    """
    given a contrast name or list of groups return a list of the files in that group
    """
    #reading in the samples
    samples = pd.read_csv(config['sampleCSVpath'])
    #there should be a column which allows you to exclude samples
    samples2 = samples.loc[samples.exclude_sample_downstream_analysis != 1]
    #read in the comparisons and make a dictionary of comparisons, comparisons needs to be in the config file
    compare_dict = load_comparisons()
    #go through the values of the dictionary and break when we find the right groups in that contrast
    grps, comparison_column = return_sample_names_group(grp)
    #take the sample names corresponding to those groups
    if comparison_column == "":
        return([""])
    grp_samples = list(set(list(samples2[samples2[comparison_column].isin(grps)].sample_name)))
    feature_counts_outdir = get_output_dir(config["project_top_level"], config["feature_counts_output_folder"])
    fc_suffix = "_featureCounts_results.txt"

    #build a list with the full path from those sample names
    fc_files = [os.path.join(feature_counts_outdir,x + fc_suffix) \
                   for x in grp_samples]
    fc_files = list(set(fc_files))
    print(fc_files)

    return(fc_files)
```

The print command is returning the correct files so I had assumed this would function

Comment: Please provide the `featurecounts_files_from_contrast` implementation.

Comment: done, it's a near copy paste of a function I have working in another pipeline which is why i'm super confused

Comment: Seems like somewhere you are doing `.list` on something. Could be in `load_comparisons`, `load_comparisonreturn_sample_names_groups`, or `get_output_dir.

Comment: Brillant! Thank you @Maarten-vd-Sande, I had a typo where I was called `.list` rather than `.join` in one of the helpers, that was driving me nuts!